# can't get File Open screen to appear in Blender? (screenshot attached)

Tags: blender

Just starting out with blender. Did something and now I can't work out how to get the basic File Open screen to appear. Have been trying for a while.

Anyone able to tell me what to do to get back to the basic File Open screen, i.e. the one at http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Open

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really the place for this question. It's not really related to game dev. However, I'll try to help.

Under the file menu is an option called Load Factory Settings. I'd try that. If you can't get to the file menu, in the top left of your screen shot, under the red close button, there's a little cube. Click that cube, then select the "Info" menu. That should allow you to access the file menu. Otherwise, instead of the "Info" menu, open the python console and enter the following:

```
bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings()
```

Then, to save those settings so you don't have to reset to the defaults every time you start Blender. Go to File->Save User Settings. Or press Ctrl+U. This should save the factory default settings over your settings that went awry.

Comment: fantastic!! - had to use the python code, and then in one of the right hand side panel's which I managed to get the python console to show...everything set just fine after that.  Not sure what went wrong?   Anyway thanks.  Want to/need to use blender for the 3D design/animations etc for a 3D game I wanted to try to build.

Comment: oh, actually whilst this works, I note that when I restart blender the screen still looks as it did in my post, so then each time I have to go in and issue the command.  Any way in blender to like "save as default" the view I want after issuing the command?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to save over bad settings.